# jquery mobile + Google Maps + Geolocation

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, geolocation, navigation

I'm creating mobile version of company site and I wonder if there is possible to make navigation snippet that will be part of page, opened with mobile browser such as WebKit or Safari (Android, Windows, iOS devices) and will display route from current to fixed place (compay office)?
Something like navigation. All with jquery mobile + Google Maps API and...? maybe is something else needed?

Some advises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can use the GOOGLE MAPS API V3. check the [Google Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_simple_v3).

You can also check  [Docs APIV3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

You'll also need to make use of [Google Maps Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

You can get your current location using html5 directly. [Geolocation in HTML5](http://html5demos.com/geo).

Answer (score 0):

That should definitely work with jQuery Mobile and the Google Maps API. It has been done before by other users. A great place to look for more information on using the two together is the jQuery Mobile forum - http://forum.jquery.com/jquery-mobile